# swift xcode - disable UIbutton from being pressed once Timer is running

Tags: swift, xcode, timer

I have a button called start that starts the **TIMER** counting , I want to `disable` it from being pressed again when the TIMER is counting other wise it makes the TIMER start counting twice as fast.

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(CountUpVC.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's best done with an observer on the timer:

```
var timer : Timer? {
    didSet {
        start.isEnabled = !(timer?.isValid ?? false)
    }
}
```

When you invalidate it, you should set it to `nil` to trigger `didSet` and enable the button again:

```
timer?.invalidate()
timer = nil
```

Comment: thanks though i still can't get it to work .     i already have a variable "var timer = Timer()   and my uibutton is called "start"     where would i place your code? @Code Different

Comment: I got the wrong property name for the UIButton. Try again now

Comment: says has no member isEnabled

Comment: What Swift version are you using? Try changing it to just `enabled`